# How to put variable string in to array in powershell?

Tags: powershell

I wanna put all values after equal to (`=`) sign separated by colon (`:`) from below "passPercent" variable into a array using PowerShell script. Meaning `array[0]=PROCESSING, array[1]=100, array[2]=75` and so on. How to do it?

```
$passPercent=PROCESSING:100.0:75:0:null:null:40:/#/app/projects/8a80808a69c899f10169c8a0d0610005/jobs/8a80808a69c899f10169c8a0da020079/runs/8a8080f169d28d430169d36a41090346:Bugs Logged = 0 Bugs Reopened = 0 Bugs Closed = 0 Total Bugs = 0
```

i did try this expression: `$array =  $passPercent  | ConvertFrom-Json` 
but was showing this error `ConvertFrom-Json : Invalid JSON primitive: PROCESSING`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the
[Split Method](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/using-the-split-method-in-powershell/):

```
$array =  $passPercent.Split(":")
```

[image]

Comment: it just store result into array by separating colon (:) like below                       array = PROCESSING 100.0 75 0 null null 42 /#/app/projects/8a80808a69c899f10169c8a0d0610005/jobs/8a80808a69c899f10169c8a0da020079/runs/8a8080f169d28d430169d4d858070494 Bugs Logged = 0 Bugs Reopened = 0 Bugs Closed = 0 Total Bugs = 0                                        i wanna store them array[0]=PROCESSING, array[1]=100 like we do other languages like shell-script

Comment: This does it. I don't see what the problem is.

Comment: i wanna put those values in below expression                                                              Write-Host "Status =" "${array[0]}" " Success Percent =" "${array[1]}"  " Total Tests =" "${array[2]}" " Time Taken =" "${array[4]}" " Run =" "${array[5]}"

Comment: Your syntax is not PowerShell. You need something like `Write-Host "Status =" , $array[0], " Success Percent =" , $array[1], " Total Tests =", $array[2]`.

Comment: thanks man, this is actually my first powershell script. that's why  facing just a little difficulty with syntax and commands.

Comment: Strange, that is **exactly** what I [suggested yesterday on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6811411/lotpings)